# How can I speed up my query?

Tags: mysql

How can I speed up this query? I use MySQL 5.1, table 'schedule' has ~ 900 K rows, and my query takes more than minute to run:

```
SELECT doc_code, `DATE`, time2, pat_code, STATUS, 
       copiedto1, copiedto2, copiedto3, copiedto4, copiedto5
FROM SCHEDULE
WHERE 1=1
AND STATUS IN (5,6,30)
AND (doc_code="K9" OR copiedto1="K9" OR copiedto2="K9" 
     OR copiedto3="K9" OR copiedto4="K9" OR copiedto5="K9")
AND `date` BETWEEN "2010/04/11" AND "2011/04/11"
AND pat_code > 0
ORDER BY `date`, doc_code, time2
```

I experimented to add different indexes, but my query doesn't want to use any of them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your table indexed on? (For the people asking about 1=1, it won't slow his query down. The optimizer would remove it and he's using it to make assembling his query easier programatically)

Comment: did you try using EXPLAIN EXTENDED before your query trying to see what happens inside of it?

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer by clicking the 'V'.

Answer (score 1):

I would change it into

```
SELECT s.* FROM (

  SELECT doc_code, `DATE`, time2, pat_code, STATUS, 
    copiedto1, copiedto2, copiedto3, copiedto4, copiedto5
  FROM SCHEDULE
  WHERE STATUS IN (5,6,30)
  AND `date` BETWEEN "2010/04/11" AND "2011/04/11"
  AND pat_code > 0
  ORDER BY `date`, doc_code, time2 ) s

WHERE (s.doc_code="K9" OR s.copiedto1="K9" OR s.copiedto2="K9" 
 OR s.copiedto3="K9" OR s.copiedto4="K9" OR s.copiedto5="K9")
```

Somewhere deep in the MySQL docs I remember reading something about `OR`'s killing the use of indexes.
I have a feeling that is going on.
If you first do a query with all `AND`'s to limit the number of records
and then do the select with `OR`'s I hope your query will run faster.

**EDIT**

http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Top10SQLPerformanceTips
Says: avoid using IN on indexed fields, it kills the performance.
Anyway, there are so many selection criteria, the query optimizer does not know where to begin.
Note that if the query optimizer 'thinks' that a criterium will use more than 25-50% *(I forgot the exact percentage)* of all fields, no index will be used.

Alternatively you might use

```
SELECT s.* FROM (

  SELECT doc_code, `DATE`, time2, pat_code, STATUS, 
    copiedto1, copiedto2, copiedto3, copiedto4, copiedto5
  FROM SCHEDULE
  USE INDEX (someIndex,someOtherIndex)   #<<<<-------------
  WHERE STATUS IN (5,6,30)
  AND `date` BETWEEN "2010/04/11" AND "2011/04/11"
  AND pat_code > 0
  ORDER BY `date`, doc_code, time2 ) s

WHERE (s.doc_code="K9" OR s.copiedto1="K9" OR s.copiedto2="K9" 
 OR s.copiedto3="K9" OR s.copiedto4="K9" OR s.copiedto5="K9")
```

The Index names or **not** equal to the fields name the index indexes.
You can find the index names in the create statement of the table, or the explain output that goes with the `explain select`.

Be carefull with forcing indexes though, measure before you finalize.
And remember a forced index query that runs fast now may run slow when the data in the table(s) changes.

Comment: What about `IN`? I think it's a synonym of `OR`s, since `status IN (5, 6, 30)` is the same as `status = 5 OR status = 6 OR status = 30`; I'm affraid it is converted into ORs internally. Anyway, I have the same feeling than you about ORs and indexes.

Comment: +1 you make a good point, added a link to give Dmitry some more background.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty optimal, did you index all of the columns in your WHERE clause?

You could try doing query in stages by prepopulating a schedule_k9 table that only has K9 codes or one that only has pat_codes > 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT doc_code, DATE, time2, pat_code, STATUS, copiedto1, copiedto2, copiedto3, copiedto4, copiedto5
FROM SCHEDULE
AND (doc_code="K9" OR copiedto1="K9" OR copiedto2="K9" OR copiedto3="K9" OR copiedto4="K9" OR copiedto5="K9")
AND pat_code > 0
AND `date` BETWEEN "2010/04/11" AND "2011/04/11"
AND STATUS IN (5,6,30)
ORDER BY `date`, doc_code, time2
```

I would have to see a sample of your table to improve the query even more (because there might be a lot of rows with a certain pattern etc...)

You can use a different type of mysql database.  Some have better read speeds, other's have better write speeds.  Here is a good article about mysql database types: [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/a-fast-and-furious-guide-to-mysql-database-engines/1058872)

I recommend you use the MyISAM table type.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work with indexes.  You can change your table's format by running this:

`ALTER TABLE SCHEDUALE CHANGE TYPE=MyISAM`

Comment: Some additional info: MySQL database is InnoDB, STATUS IN (5,6,30) represents ~30% of table data, doc_code="K9" is ~1% of table data, and  pat_code > 0 condition filters out 10% of the data. Columns copiedto1-copiedto5 contains insignificant number of entries.

Answer (score 0):

A composite index on (date, status) should make your query snappy.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I tried to add index on (date, status) - didn't help. I already have index on (`date`, doc_code, time2) that as I use in ORDER BY clause. But EXPLAIN shows that key = NULL (not picking up any index).

Comment: @Dimitri K. did you try forcing the index using query hints?

Comment: You could try to `Analyse table SCHEDULE` to update index stats. Hom many distinct date do you have?

Comment: Thank you all for suggestions. Finally, decided to make extra conditions optional, so full condition will be used with a text that it's not optimal (doc_code="K9" OR copiedto1="K9" OR copiedto2="K9" OR copiedto3="K9" OR copiedto4="K9" OR copiedto5="K9").  (doc_code="K9") will be used in 99% cases. Full condition unlikely can be optimized, and will rarely be used.